# Checking library version of shared library (so-file) in autoconf

Tags: c, shared, autoconf

Libraries typically have a package/release version as well as a library version. These have very different semantics.

Is there a standard way to check the availability of a library with a given *library version* using Autoconf, i.e., a macro in configure.ac?

Things that can be done, but are bad in my opinion (correct me if I am wrong):

1. Rely on the name of the postfix of the so-file. Weak verification.
2. Add artificial function in each version of the library and check for this in the standard Autoconf way. Ugly and assumes that I build the library.
3. Embed the lib version in the header file, check that this matches with grep-ish tricks, and assume that this matches the version in the lib. Risk of mismatch between header file and library and assumes I build the library.

What I want is a solution that inspects the *actual* library version
embedded in the library itself. I feel stupid, but I have googled
quite a lot and do not find anything.

Comment: PKG_CHECK_MODULES check library version hold in library's *.pc file.

Comment: Thank you alexander, but if I understand things correctly, the information is taken from separate .pc files and involves another tool, pkg-config?

I should add that minimizing dependencies is very important in this project. I am a cryptographer and have implemented a non-standard multiparty protocol, some of which is my own theoretical work. Currently I only rely on autotools and GMP. Every additional dependency effectively adds untrusted developers. Hence my resistance to what would otherwise by quite natural.

Comment: The postfix of the library may or may not be the source version it was built from. Some libraries use ABI compatibility patterns here; e.g. libevent 2.1.8, when producing a shared object, has the postfix 2.1.6.